# ASP.NET MVC5 Client-side Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an amount field in a view that is required if a checkbox is checked.

Once Razor renders the View with Model data, and a user checks a checkbox without a corresponding amount entered.  The Validation message appears.  If I de-select that checkbox, the validation message does not disappear.

I've tried to use jquery to remove all the rules generated, but if the user were to checkbox again, prior to post back, those validation rules would have been removed (unless I store them... which is getting really ugly.)

Is there an acceptable way to re-validate client-side with the same requirements in the MVC Model?

Model:

```
[Display(Name = "Include Amount")]
public bool IncludeAmount { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Amount")]
[RequiredIf("IncludeAmount", TargetValue = true, ErrorMessage = "Amount is required.")]
[MaxDigits(10, 2)]
[RegularExpression(RegularExpressions.Money, ErrorMessage = ErrorMessages.NumericValueInvalidFormat)]
[GreaterThanZero]
public Nullable<decimal> Amount { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<td class="dataEntryLabel" colspan="2">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IncludeAmount)
</td>
<td class="dataEntryField" colspan="2">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IncludeAmount, new { id = "IncludeAmount" })
    <span class="dollar-sign">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Amount, "{0:F}", new { id = "Amount", disabled = "disabled" })</span>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount)
</td>
```

JavaScript (Client-side):

```
function fixUnobtrusiveValidations() {
    var form = getForm();
    (<any>$).validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
}

function onClickCheckBoxIncludeAmount(){
        fixUnobtrusiveValidations();
}

$('IncludeAmount').click(onClickCheckBoxIncludeAmount);
```

Comment: Try this https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Flexible-Conditional-37ae638e/sourcecode?fileId=65995&pathId=91939366

Here is some explanation https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stuartleeks/2012/09/07/flexible-conditional-validation-with-asp-net-mvc-adding-client-side-support/

Comment: What plugin are you using for your custom attributes (or are these you own?). There is no reason to reparse the validator. And do not set the `id` attribute - your just overwriting the id generated by the `HtmlHelper` methods

Answer (score 0):

Try this to disable the client side validation on onclick events 
Refer: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onclick

```
$("#myform").validate({
    onclick: false,
});
```

OR

```
$("#yourChkboxID").validate({
    onclick: false,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```html
if (!($('#IncludeAmount').checked)){
   toggleValidatorVisibility($('#Amount'), false);
}

function toggleValidatorVisibility(element: any, value) {
  var td: any = element.closest('td');
  if (value) {
       td.find('span.field-validation-error').show();
  } else {
       td.find('span.field-validation-error').empty();
  }
}
```